# Failure/Error: visit movies_url NameError: undefined local variable or method `movies_url' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1:0x007ff450c81800>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, tdd, capybara

I am just getting started with RSpec. I receive the error of having an undefined variable or method 'movies_url' when running my spec file. This is what it looks like when I run rspec:

```
bundle exec rspec spec/list_movies_spec.rb
F

Failures:

  1) when viewing the list of movies should show the movies
     Failure/Error: visit movies_url
     NameError:
       undefined local variable or method `movies_url' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1:0x007ff450c81800>
     # ./spec/list_movies_spec.rb:24:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.01881 seconds
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/list_movies_spec.rb:4 # when viewing the list of movies should show the movies

Randomized with seed 45910
```

`list_movies_spec.rb` this is my test I am running.

```
require "spec_helper"

describe "when viewing the list of movies" do
  it "should show the movies" do

movie1 = Movie.create(title: "Iron Man",
                      rating: "PG-13",
                      total_gross: 318412101.00,
                      description: "Tony Stark builds an armored suit to fight the throes of evil",
                      released_on: "2008-05-02")

movie2 = Movie.create(title: "Superman",
                      rating: "PG",
                      total_gross: 134218018.00,
                      description: "Clark Kent grows up to be the greatest super-hero",
                      released_on: "1978-12-15")

movie3 = Movie.create(title: "Spider-Man",
                      rating: "PG-13",
                      total_gross: 403706375.00,
                      description: "Peter Parker gets bit by a genetically modified spider",
                      released_on: "2002-05-03")

    visit movies_url

    expect(page).to have_text("3 Movies")
    expect(page).to have_text("Iron Man")
    expect(page).to have_text("Batman")
    expect(page).to have_text("Captain America")
  end
end
```

`Gemfile` this is what I have installed with Capybara and RSpec versions.

```
group :test, :development do
  gem "minitest"
  gem "rspec-rails", "2.13.1"
end

group :test do
  gem "capybara", "2.1.0"
end
```

I do have the proper route that should be matching the spec movies_url.

```
rake routes
Prefix Verb URI Pattern       Controller#Action
movies GET  /movies(.:format) movies#index
```

On my console I run:

```
app.movies_url
=> "http://www.example.com/movies"
```

I have looked else where for clues but I have not had any success. I think it is an RSpec and Capybara version issue?

More details:

```
gem list rspec

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

rspec-core (3.3.1, 2.13.1)
rspec-expectations (3.3.0, 2.13.0)
rspec-mocks (3.3.1, 2.13.1)
rspec-rails (3.3.2, 2.13.1)
rspec-support (3.3.0)

gem list capybara

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

capybara (2.1.0)
```

Comment: Add this at the start of the RSpec test and see if it helps `include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers`

Comment: @Coderhs i get this `Failure/Error: visit movies_url
     ArgumentError:
       Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host parameter, set default_url_options[:host], or set :only_path to true`

Comment: That was after require 'spec_helper' before that i get `uninitialized constant Rails (NameError)`

Comment: Can you place this in your test.rb `Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host]= 'localhost:3000'`

Comment: It works @Coderhs ! Thanks! I got another error but it was expected. Thanks!

Comment: Okay going to put those two comment as an answer as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place this in spec file.

```
include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
```

The above code, would make all the urls helpers such as root_path, movies_url accessible in your test. But to visit we should define the host in the test.rb environment file as well. For which place the below code in test.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host]= 'localhost:3000'
```